# install eucalyptus on centOS error

Tags: installation, centos, eucalyptus

I'm trying to install eucalyptus on centOS 6.2. I followed the steps for [installing eucalyptus on centos](http://www.eucalyptus.com/download/eucalyptus/centos) on the official website.

When I came to the point to install eucalyptus, I chose to use rpm. It's the chapter
**Install RPMs on the Front End**
on the website. The command I type is:

```
rpm -Uvh aoetools-21-1.el4.x86_64.rpm \
 euca-axis2c-1.6.0-1.x86_64.rpm \
 euca-rampartc-1.3.0-1.x86_64.rpm \
 vblade-14-1mdv2008.1.x86_64.rpm \
 vtun-3.0.2-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm \
 lzo2-2.02-3.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm\
 perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-Random-0.04-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm\
 perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-RSA-0.25-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm\
 perl-Crypt-X509-0.32-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm\
 python25-2.5.1-bashton1.x86_64.rpm\
 python25-devel-2.5.1-bashton1.x86_64.rpm\
 python25-libs-2.5.1-bashton1.x86_64.rpm
```

and the error I got:

```
warning: aoetools-21-1.el4.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 217521f6: NOKEY
warning: vblade-14-1mdv2008.1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 78d019f5: NOKEY
warning: vtun-3.0.2-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 6b8d79e6: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) is needed by euca-rampartc-1.3.0-6.el5.x86_64
    libssl.so.6()(64bit) is needed by euca-rampartc-1.3.0-6.el5.x86_64
    libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) is needed by vtun-3.0.2-1.el5.rf.x86_64
    libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) is needed by perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-Random-0.04-1.el5.rf.x86_64
    libssl.so.6()(64bit) is needed by perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-Random-0.04-1.el5.rf.x86_64
    libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) is needed by perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-RSA-0.25-1.el5.rf.x86_64
    libssl.so.6()(64bit) is needed by perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-RSA-0.25-1.el5.rf.x86_64
    libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) is needed by python25-2.5.1-bashton1.x86_64
    libdb-4.3.so()(64bit) is needed by python25-2.5.1-bashton1.x86_64
    libexpat.so.0()(64bit) is needed by python25-2.5.1-bashton1.x86_64
    libreadline.so.5()(64bit) is needed by python25-2.5.1-bashton1.x86_64
    libssl.so.6()(64bit) is needed by python25-2.5.1-bashton1.x86_64
```

How could I solve this problem? I hope someone has been trapped in the same situation as I am.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the dependencies did not get resolved which is why the installation did not proceed.  I also faced exactly the same problem, so here is the solution I found. You will have to download a few RPMs in order to install the dependencies required.

My system's architecture is i386. Replace  by X86_64

1. libcrypto.so.6() and libssl.so.6() : To get these files, you will have to install the RPM openssl098e-17.el6.centos.2..rpm
2. libdb-4.3.so() : Install compat-db43-4.3-24-15.el6..rpm
3. libreadline.so.5() : Install compat-readline5-5.2-17.1.el6..rpm
4. libexpat.so.0() : Install compat-expat1-1.95.8-8.el6..rpm

After installing these dependencies, go for the regular installation of the RPMs.

Comment: I missed the architecture just before .rpm
Please add x86_64 between the two dots just before rpm.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

eucalyptus 2.0 do not support centos 6.2. Centos 5 uses xen while centos 6 uses kvm. You will have to wait for eucalyptus 3.1 for this.

Answer (score 1):

Also if you'd like to quickly test Eucalyptus 3.1 and deploy a cloud in under 30 minutes, you can download [Eucalyptus FastStart](http://go.eucalyptus.com/Download-FastStart.html?LeadSourceDetails=Eucalyptus%20Website&Offer=Free%20Trial&OfferDetails=Download%20FastStart&OfferURL=http://go.eucalyptus.com/Download-FastStart.html), which runs on CentOS 6.2 and KVM on a minimum of 2 machines.

You can watch this short [FastStart video](http://www.eucalyptus.com/video/faststart-eucalyptus-31) that walks you through the installation.

Answer (score 0):

You were asking about Eucalyptus 2 but 3.1 is out now and KVM is supported.  It should be much easier to [install Eucalyptus 3.1 on Centos 6](http://www.eucalyptus.com/download/eucalyptus/centos-6).  Here is a snippet from the install docs:

> Install the KVM driver appropriate to your hardware.
>
> For systems with Intel processors:
>
> ```
> modprobe kvm_intel
> modprobe vhost_net
> ```